# Jenkins build fails for yarn bin lerna command

Tags: node.js, git, jenkins, yarnpkg

I'm trying to use `yarn bin lerna` command in pipeline for jenkins but it fails as it tries to fetch/update package git repository with ssh credentials.

Using below Jenkinsfile in multibranch project.

```groovy
stages {
    stage('Install NPM Deps') {
        steps {
            configFileProvider([configFile(
                fileId: 'npm-auth',
                targetLocation: '.npmrc'
            )]) {
            withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'cred-id', keyFileVariable: 'KEY')]) {
            withEnv(['GIT_SSH=ssh -i ${KEY} -l git']) {
                script {
                    docker.image("node").inside("-u0 -vnode_home:/.npm") {
                        sh 'yarn'
                        sh 'yarn clean --yes'
                        sh 'yarn bootstrap'
                        sh '$(yarn bin lerna) version ${VERSION}'    
                        
                      //sh 'yarn test'
                      //sh 'yarn deploy'

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error when running pipeline.

```
+ yarn bin lerna
+ /var/jenkins/workspace/test-lib/node_modules/.bin/lerna version patch
lerna notice cli v3.22.1
lerna info versioning independent
lerna info ci enabled
lerna ERR! Error: Command failed: git remote update
lerna ERR! error: cannot run ssh -l git: No such file or directory
lerna ERR! fatal: unable to fork
lerna ERR! error: Could not fetch origin
lerna ERR! 
lerna ERR! Fetching origin
lerna ERR! lerna Command failed: git remote update
lerna ERR! lerna error: cannot run ssh -l git: No such file or directory
lerna ERR! lerna fatal: unable to fork
lerna ERR! lerna error: Could not fetch origin
lerna ERR! lerna 
lerna ERR! lerna Fetching origin
lerna ERR! lerna
```

I've tried creating `~/.ssh/id_rsa` file out of the key but still fails.

UPDATE:
After updating `GIT_SSH` to `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` error has changed.

```
lerna info versioning independent
lerna info ci enabled
lerna ERR! Error: Command failed: git remote update
lerna ERR! Host key verification failed.
lerna ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
lerna ERR! 
lerna ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
lerna ERR! and the repository exists.
lerna ERR! error: Could not fetch origin
lerna ERR! 
lerna ERR! Fetching origin
lerna ERR!
```

I'm guessing it is due to prompt of adding host to known host file.

**UPDATE**
So as predicted adding `GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh -i ${KEY} -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -l git` solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The environment variable `GIT_SSH` (as distinct from `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`) *cannot* have options.  See [the main `git` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git), which says in part:

> `GIT_SSH`, `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`
> ...
> `$GIT_SSH_COMMAND` takes precedence over `$GIT_SSH`, and is interpreted
> by the shell, which allows additional arguments to be included.
> `$GIT_SSH` on the other hand must be just the path to a program
> which can be a wrapper shell script, if additional arguments are
> needed).

Clearly you wanted to use `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`, not `GIT_SSH`, here.

That said, there's something else odd here:

> ```
> withEnv(['GIT_SSH=ssh -i ${KEY} -l git']) {
> ```

Why is the `-i ${KEY}` missing?

Comment: Yeah I see will try with GIT_SSH_COMMAND but regarding `-i ${KEY}` I'm also not sure why error output is not showing that.